# How to replace a letter in string by position in python 3.x

Tags: python, string, list, position

I am trying to create a 'hangman' game. And for that I need to take the word the player is trying to guess, and turn all the letters they haven't yet guessed into `" _ "`

So let's say I have:

```
letters_guessed = [q, r, u, a, p]
secret_word = "dragon"
```

How can I turn it into: `_ r a _ _ _`?

Comment: What have you tried, and what exactly is the problem with it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Several possible solutions here, one being:

```
letters_guessed = ["q", "r", "u", "a", "p"]

secret_word = "dragon"

output = ""
for char in secret_word:
    if char in letters_guessed:
        x = char
    else:
        x = "_"
    output += x

print(output)
# Output:  _ra___
```

Put it in a function afterwards:

```
def hangman(word, guessed):
    output = ""
    for char in word:
        if char in guessed:
            x = char
        else:
            x = "_"
        output += x
    return output
```

---

Alternatively, you can use a list comprehension altogether:

```
letters_guessed = ["q", "r", "u", "a", "p"]
secret_word = "dragon"
secret_list = "".join([char if char in letters_guessed else "_" 
                       for char in list(secret_word)])
print(secret_list)
```